# How to add a button before and after a progress bar

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I dont find a ways to add a Button directly before and after a progress bar.

The result is like: voting down and voting up something, and the progress bar then reacts.

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">+</a>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progU" style="width: <%=question.percentU%>%">
        <span class="voteText"><%=question.percentU%>%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progD" style="width: <%=question.percentD%>%">
        <span class="voteText"><%=question.percentD%>%</span>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">-</a>
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the progress bars and buttons in separate divs then align them horizontally like this:

```
<!-- div to contain the progress bar -->
<div class="progress-container">
<!-- Div for left progress bar buttons -->
  <div class="left-progress-bar">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">+</a>
  </div>
<!-- Div for center progress bar -->
  <div class="center-progress-bar">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progU" style="width: 60%">
        <span class="voteText">60%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progD" style="width: 40%">
        <span class="voteText">40%</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Div for right progress bar buttons -->
  <div class="right-progress-bar">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">-</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now apply this css to it to keep them horizontally align

```
.progress-container{
  width: 300px;
}
.left-progress-bar{
  float:left;width:5%;
}
.center-progress-bar{
  float:left;width:90%;
}
.right-progress-bar{
  float:left;width:5%;
}
```